# brew install with modified source

Tags: xcode, macos, homebrew, xcode-command-line-tools

How do I run `brew install` with local changes to the Homebrew source code?

Running `brew install` discards my changes, even if I've committed them.

#### More Details

When I run `brew install heroku/brew/heroku`,

I get:

```
Error: Xcode alone is not sufficient on High Sierra.
Install the Command Line Tools:
  xcode-select --install
```

However, I don't want to install the Command Line Tools (and I don't want to update macOS right now, and so I can't update Xcode either). So, I edited the Homebrew source code (in `/usr/local/Homebrew`) to make `MacOS::Xcode.needs_clt_installed?` (defined in `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/xcode.rb`) return `false`.

But, when I run `brew install heroku/brew/heroku` again, it overwrites my changes to the Homebrew source code.

Comment: Did you try `brew install -s heroku/brew/heroku`?